# How to make a request to a GET request (PHP) from swift 4

Tags: php, ios, swift4.2

**My Goal:**

Upload some parameters to MYSQL database from my iOS app

**What I have done:**

I have a working php file that successfully updates my database.
When I enter the url into my browser, it echoes the sql string and successfully updates the database

**The URL I need to "call" in swift**

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/myPhpGetRequest.php?&uuid=FGA847B3-F51C-4301-BF46-8B3970A3B193&myFirstparameter=pass
```

**My research**

Most of my research has led to questions that rely on JSON.
Do I have to use JSON or can I "silently" call this URL?

**TL:DR:**

I need to call a URL to upload parameters to a database and I am currently lost.
I already have an Alamofire dependency in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really asking how to make an http request in swift.

Look into: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

```
import Alamofire

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.mywebsite.com/myPhpGetRequest.php?&uuid=FGA847B3-F51C-4301-BF46-8B3970A3B193&myFirstparameter=pass")
```